# MySQL ADD CONSTRAINT doesn't create RESTRICT rule

Tags: mysql

I need to add foreign key to MySQL table with RESTRICT rule, and something really strange happens:

When I do:

```
ALTER TABLE smartphone_model_work 
ADD CONSTRAINT SmartphoneMW_Work
FOREIGN KEY(SmartphoneWorkID)
REFERENCES smartphone_work(SmartphoneWorkID)
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

It creates foreign key with "NO ACTION" rule, while I need "RESTRICT". But when I do:

```
ALTER TABLE smartphone_model_work 
ADD CONSTRAINT SmartphoneMW_Work
FOREIGN KEY(SmartphoneWorkID)
REFERENCES smartphone_work(SmartphoneWorkID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It creates "CASCADE" constraint as expected.

So how to create RESTRICT rule?

My MySQL version is 5.7.20

Thanks.

Comment: Form the MySql doc _RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table. Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause._ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Hmm... When I execute command:

    ALTER TABLE smartphone_model_work 
    ADD CONSTRAINT SmartphoneMW_Work
    FOREIGN KEY(SmartphoneWorkID)
    REFERENCES smartphone_work(SmartphoneWorkID);

It really creates RESTRICT rule. But why is that? Why only NOT pointing RESTRICT keyword creates RESTRICT rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for whatever reason correct query is:

```
ALTER TABLE smartphone_model_work 
ADD CONSTRAINT SmartphoneMW_Work
FOREIGN KEY(SmartphoneWorkID)
REFERENCES smartphone_work(SmartphoneWorkID);
```

I.e. to create RESTRICT you should NOT use RESTRICT keyword. Looks like it's some kind of bug.